# Task :react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, package.json

My APP was running fine but while I tried a new installation it shows the error - Task :react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED. Below code might help you to address the issue. 
My **package.json** is given below:

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-search-filter": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-webview": "5.8.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue on this error. Any help???

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some linking problem.

I just faced same problem and solved it on React-Native v0.6,here's my solution:

1. JUST FOLLOWING THIS [TUTORIAL](https://www.toptal.com/react-native/react-native-camera-tutorial)
2. EXECUTE THIS `react-native run-android --no-jetifier

`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.